# Importing JavaScript files with the same name as directory they're inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, webpack, structure

In my React and Webpack project, I have the following project structure of React components:

```
Component/
├── Component.jsx
├── index.jsx
└── styles.css
```

The `index.jsx` file simply imports and exports `Component.jsx`; the reason being that in files that require it, it allows the usage of the following:

```
import Component from '../Component'
```

as opposed to

```
import Component from '../Component/Component'
```

However this seems like it may be an unnecessary extra step which requires all new components to follow suit.

With this in mind, my question is: Can I have the best of both worlds? I want to be able to only have `Component.jsx` and `styles.css` in my directory, but not have to use the name twice in my `import` declaration.

Comment: `import Component from './'` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me suggest you the following structure I personally like:

Your component tree structure (As an example every component has a different folder structure. It is up to you to keep it clean and tidy. Index.jsx in components folder just normalizes access to those components whoever needs them):

```
src/components/
    Butter/
        Butter.jsx
        index.jsx
    Beets/
        Beets.jsx
    Cabbage/
        index.jsx
    Meat.jsx
index.jsx
```

Content of `components/index.jsx`

```
export Butter from './Butter/index.jsx';
export Beets from './Beets/Beets.jsx';
export Cabbage from './Cabbage/index.jsx';
export Meat from './Meat.jsx';
```

Some container Borscht.jsx somewhere else in your project which uses those components

```
import {
    Beets,
    Cabbage,
} from 'src/components';
```

Comment: For people having issues with `export X from 'Y';` syntax, I found I had to change it to `export {default as X} from 'Y';` in order to get it to work, more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating

Answer (score 1):

If your folder already tells you which is the component name, you don't need to put it again in the file name inside it. I use this approach.

All modern editors already solves the trouble with two equal names (`ComponentA/index.jsx` and `ComponentB/index.jsx`) for us, by adding the folder name in the tabs.

[image]

Note that this is an Vue component, but it's the same thing for React.

Answer (score 1):

One option for webpack users is to install [**directory-named-webpack-plugin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin)

Install, and then add the following to Webpack's config file:

```js
var DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");

resolve: {
    plugins: [
        new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

When using `require("component/foo")` *and* the path `"component/foo"` is resolved to a directory, Webpack will try to look for `component/foo/foo.js` as the entry point.

**Caution**: While this approach does allow webpack to resolve filenames when building and bundling, your intellisense / tooling options are a different beast altogether.  Unless they also have similar functionality, you may lose *Go To Definition* and *Intellisense* support by not providing the full reference statically.